# Limit access to Data by record owner in .NETCore

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm relatively new to .NETCore 2.0 and want to know the best way to ensure a person can only view/edit records that they created and are the "Owner" of that record.

I know how to add the current user to the Create object before saving from the controller, but I am not sure the best way to check for Edit/Read access.  Should I keep this logic in the Controller?  Or enforce this on the Model/Repository?

I have a Repository function to edit a "Trade" object.

```
public void EditTrade(Trade trade, string currentUserId)
    {
        if(trade.Owner != currentUserId)
            throw new Exception("Not the correct user");
        context.Trade.Add(trade);
    }
```

I feel like this a lot of coding across my entire app and not sure if there was a more built-in way to check with Entity Framework or .NET's Identity packages.

If it helps, I am not concerned about admins seeing everything.  Every user can only see their own records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keeping it in the repository should be fine. I'm not sure if how you generate the records, i suggest that in your repository you should have the ff:

```
public IEnumerable<Trade> GetTradesByUser(userId){
     return _context.Trades
    .Where(t => t.UserId == userId)
    .ToList();
}
```

use this to show all trades of the logged in user.

then your edit function can be

```
public void EditTrade(Trade trade)
{
    _context.Trade.Add(trade);
}
```

since you are sure that he did not see anyone else's record.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First, You can use .net core identity's ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)) (if that's what your application needs) or you can implement your own user's managing logic.

Secondly, if I understand correct trades can only be manipulated by a user who created that.

There are 2 scenarios

1. Do you want to show all the trades in the system?
2. Do you want to show only the trades created by the user?

Scenario 1:
If only you show all the trades for the user you may need to build a logic in your controller preventing the user from modifying the Trade created by others. (similar to @Redan suggestion, including more of view logic as well)

Scenario 2: No validation required. you can manipulate data as you will be displaying records created by the user.

either way, you need to associate User Entity with Trade Entity and persist user data. I also think it will be the same for any other entities.